# How do you create a 2d world then view it in 3d?

Tags: opengl, 2d, 3d, projection

I have been learning OpenGL for a while now and have a pretty good understanding so far.

What I would like to know is if I create a 2D game in Orthographic Projection, is it possible to switch to a perspective projection and view the scene without having to manually adjust the camera etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the geometry that your world consists of and how you set your orthographic projection and camera up relative to that world.

Most of the time, when people make 2D games with orthographic projections, they don't bother actually creating 3D geometry. Usually everything is a quad with a texture applied, or simple 3D geometry without much actual "depth" (since the projection renders that depth relatively useless). Thus, switching to a 3D view with perspective would result in a flat or oddly-spaced world with a lot of Paper Mario-style thin objects.

Similarly, orthographic projection parameters are usually set up to map world units to pixels, or similar. It's *possible* to simply substitute a orthographic projection with a perspective one, but unless you've done a lot of careful pre-planning with the camera parameters and field-of-view, et cetera, you're likely to get a image of the world that is too "zoomed in" or too "zoomed out" and thus you'd want to make at least some *minor* adjustments to the camera in the perspective mode to account for this.

Without more information about the background behind your question (what is the overall problem you are trying to solve), the answer is basically that "it depends." It's potentially doable in general, but whether it will work in practice for your project is hard to say.